# Unable to select <a> based on its text and then add an attribute named "target" to it using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following link inside my web page:

```
<a href="http://*****/management/Shared Documents/13423423">Attachments and Documents</a>
```

Now I want to select this link based on its text "Attachments and Documents", and set a target attribute for it.

So I tried the following:

```
var tgb = $('a:contains("Attachments and Documents")')[0];
tgb.attr('target', '_blank');
```

But I got the following exception :

> TypeError: tgb.attr is not a function

Comment: Remove the `[0]`.  That breaks the element out of the jQuery object.  `attr()` is a jQuery method.

Comment: The answer is not to wrap the tgb in $() people.  It's to not break out of the jQuery object in the first place and create the extra work....

Comment: You are not addressing the problem.  You are fixing the problem rather than preventing the problem.  It's a first step towards spagetti code and shows a lack of understanding of what the code is doing.

Comment: `attr` method is part of jquery spec, is not part of DOMElement, what you get when getting `[0]` from your call is a dom element and not a jquery reference...

Comment: So we teach him why it is broken and try to encourage him to learn.  Not just simply go with the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you use index (`[0]`), `tab` is no more a jQuery object. To get the jQuery function `attr()` you have to wrap `tgb` with `$`:

```js
var tgb = $('a:contains("Attachments and Documents")')[0];
$(tgb).attr('target', '_blank');

// to demonstrate result
console.log(tgb)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://*****/management/Shared Documents/13423423">Attachments and Documents</a>
```

Comment: I dont get why you got a DwnV. So Upv for a right answer too :)

Comment: I also got a dwnV. Weird jajaja

Answer (score 1):

`attr()` is a jQuery function. You need to target your variable using jQuery methods

```
$(tgb)
```

Hope this helps :)

```js
var tgb = $('a:contains("Attachments and Documents")')[0];
$(tgb).attr('target', '_blank');
console.log(tgb);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://*****/management/Shared Documents/13423423">Attachments and Documents</a>
```

Comment: If DownV, please comment so i can improve :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var tgb = $('a:contains("Attachments and Documents")');
tgb.attr('target', '_blank');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://*****/management/Shared Documents/13423423">Attachments and Documents</a>
```

The issue with your logic was the `[0]` that you were putting on the tgb.  `[0]` on a jQuery object breaks the element out of the jQuery object and returns the native Element.  There are various reasons why you would want to do this, such as if you wanted to access element properties and you don't want to go through the jQuery `prop()` or `attr()` method.

However in your case, you are trying to use the `attr()` method off of tgb.  However, `attr()` is a jQuery method.  Since you broke the element out of the jQuery object, this will not work.

Rather than turning the tgb back into a jQuery object, simply take off the `[0]`.  This fixes your issue, and removes the need to create another jQuery object which, give the snippet you provided, is unnecessary work.

Optionally, if you *do* want it to be a native Element you could just set the attribute directly.

```
var tgb = $(...)[0];
tgb.setAttribute('href', newValue);
//or
tgb.href = newValue;
```